# R: (Formattable) Is there a way to make color_bar with condition?

Tags: r, formattable

I'm trying to make "yes" in green color bar "no" in red color bar.. but with the code below only turn the words into green/red.. i tried doing `x ~ formattable::style(color_bar = ifelse(x == "yes", "green"` but it does not work that way..

`YesNo = formattable::color_bar("red")` with this code I get this output.. but i'm trying to get "yes" in green and "no" in red..
[image: Something like this but turn "yes" into green and "no" to red..]

```
df = data.frame(YesNo = c("yes","no","yes","no"), 
            Numbers = c(4, 5, 10, 10))
df

rownames(df) = c("Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4")
df

formattable(df)

    
  sign_formatter <- formattable::formatter("span", 
                                          style = x ~ formattable::style(color = ifelse(x == "yes", "green", 
                                                                                        ifelse(x == "no", "red", "green"))))
```

Comment: In your otherpost, you had the line `formattable(df, list(
  YesNo = sign_formatter,
  Numbers = color_tile("transparent","lightgreen")))`

Comment: Yes correct but that only turns the word itself into green and red.. what I want is changing the color bar instead of the word itself

Comment: you meant the background as in the `color_tile`?

Comment: something like in the picture i just uploaded.. with the code `YesNo = formattable::color_bar("red")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could create a condition in `background-color`  and pass that in `formattable`

```
color_formatter <- formattable::formatter(
  "span",
  style = x ~ style(
    color = 'white',
    'background-color' =
      ifelse(x == "yes", "green", "red")
            ))
formattable::formattable(df, list(
  YesNo = color_formatter,
  Numbers = formattable::color_tile("transparent","lightgreen")))
```

-output

[image]